# C++ Catch and throw: I am trying to an integer array and it is not catching the array properly

Tags: c++

So I have this simple class, that throw an array, so the main can catch it and interpret it

```
#include "r0t0r.h"

using namespace std;


rotor::r0t0r(){
    int a[2]={5,6};
    throw a;
}
```

In my main, I try to catch this array:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    try{
        r0t0r a;
        std::cout << "123" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(int e[2]){
        std::cout << e[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but my output is some gibberrish.

Help?

Edit:

I just tried the below, it is due the empty constructor.

```
class rotor{
    public:
  rotor();
    rotor(int a[2]);
};

rotor::rotor(){
  int b[2]={12,2};
  throw b;
}

rotor::rotor(int a[2]){

    throw a;
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    try{
      //int b[2]={12,2};
      //rotor a(b); 
//this output perfect with a contructor with argument


      rotor a;
//this output gibberish


    }
    catch(int e[2]){
        std::cout << e[0] << std::endl;


    }

}
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error on my machine

Comment: Probably best to copy your output here for us to see.

Comment: it works for my other classes, but for some reason, it output 12312312312

Comment: some big and different number

Comment: ok, now i put the class in my main, the error disappear, this is weird

Comment: Can you post all of your code.

Comment: @Tomchan are you sure about `rotor::r0t0r()`? If this was meant as constructor, the qualifier doesn't match the class name.

Comment: i m trying to change machine and try

Comment: yeah. it should be r0t0r::r0t0r @Tom chan

Comment: The guy with the russian name is right, it is due to the constructor! BUY WHY?

Comment: I amended the code a lil bit, cos it s homework....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        int a[2]={5,6};
        std::cout << "Address of A " << a << std::endl;
        throw a;
    }
    catch(int e[2])
    {
        std::cout << "Type of E " << typeid(e).name() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Address of E " << e << std::endl;
        std::cout << e[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This now outputs the type of the caught object:

```
 $ ./a.out 
 Address of A 0x7fff55986a40
 Type of E Pi
 Address of E 0x7fff55986a40
 5
```

`Pi` being a pointer to int:

```
$ c++filt Pi
int*
```

What is going on here is the decay of the array `a[2]` to a pointer - `int *`. Read more about array to pointer decay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

What appears to be throw and catch of the contents of the array by value is in fact a throw and catch of its *pointer* by value instead.

You are throwing the address of a stack variable, and then attempting to access it beyond its lifetime. *This is undefined behaviour*.

This will appear to work in trivial cases such as mine as nothing has yet overwritten the stack, but will then fail as the program gains complexity.

To get the behaviour you expect, consider using `std::array<int>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        std::array<int, 2> a={{5,6}};
        throw a;
    }
    catch(std::array<int, 2> e)
    {
        std::cout << e[0] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This definitely make sense, but can you explain this only apply to the empty constructor??

Comment: Both constructors look equally suspect, and both suffer from undefined behaviour. However, the constructor taking a array argument receives a decayed pointer-to-an-array which is already on the stack  when it's called and is probably still there when the exception is caught, so the problem is not apparent.

Comment: ya, i just try it out now with a constructor with a bit more code in it and it s not working again

Comment: Just updated the question.  My solution requires C++11

Comment: No. the TL;DR answer is that `std::array` is a class which enforces copy-by-value semantics and to which array-to-pointer decay does not apply. 
This means that a copy is made when the object is thrown and caught.

Comment: Yes. Or `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing an array address and catch it with an int, Throwing an int value will resolve your problem.

Comment: i am throwing an array and catching an array, doesnt it work?

Comment: @KishanKumar: It might, because the program exhibits undefined behaviour.